# Using multiple List WebElements in one for loop using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
List<WebElement> one =driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id='divdiscountcheckbox'] input[type='checkbox']")); 
        List<WebElement> two =driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id='divdiscountcheckbox'] em")); 
        
        for(WebElement each :two) 
        {
        System.out.println(each.getText());
        }
```

Query:I need to do one.isSelected + two.gettext() using only one for loop and both the list size are same. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<WebElement> one = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id='divdiscountcheckbox'] input[type='checkbox']"));
    List<WebElement> two = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id='divdiscountcheckbox'] em"));
    
    // if sizes are not equal
    int oneSize = one.size();
    int twoSize = two.size();
    int maxSize = 0;
    if (oneSize > twoSize) {
        maxSize = twoSize;
    }
    else {
        maxSize = oneSize;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
        // .isSelected() made by click?
        one.get(i).click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            
        }
        System.out.println(two.get(i).getText());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks and below code helped me:
System.out.println(ss.get(i).getText()+ ' '+ options.get(i).isSelected() );